# How to make a <div> show only when a certain <select> dropdown option is selected? The <select> options are populated with the ng-repeat directive

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs

I have a `select` dropdown list populated with the angularjs `ng-repeat` directive. I would like for a `div` to show only when a certain option is selected.

Here is the code:

```
<select type="text"
  class="form-control"
  ng-model="vm.request.requestType"  
  name="requestType" id="requestType"
  placeholder=""
  required>
   <option selected></option>
   <option value="test">test</option>
   <option ng-repeat="requestType in vm.requestTypes">{{requestType}}</option>
</select>

<script>
    $(function() {
      $("#requestType").change(function () {
        if ($("#test").is(":selected")) {
          $("#continueCheckbox").show();
        } else {
          $("#continueCheckbox").hide();
        }
      }).trigger('change');
    });
</script>

<div id="continueCheckbox">
  <input type="checkbox"
     name="continueCheckbox"
     value="continueCheckbox">
     Check this box to continue, and to confirm that you have read the 
     Documentation
</div>
```

The "test" option is just for testing if the function works. Currently, the checkbox displays no matter what is selected, and never disappears.

Comment: Is the angular project yours? If so, don't use jQuery.  See the answers (and comments) below for a variety of options to accomplish what you want with Angular: `ng-if`, `ng-hide`, `ng-show`, `ng-class` and / or `ng-style` are all potential ways to do what you want with Angular.

Comment: Did you figure out how to get data into your angular app from your database?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I highly recommend not mixing AngularJS and jQuery. Both are DOM manipulation frameworks and do not work well together. Here is one way you could accomplish what you are after with AngularJS:

```
<div id="continueCheckbox" ng-if="vm.request.requestType === 'test'">
    <input type="checkbox"
           name="continueCheckbox"
           value="continueCheckbox">
        Check this box to continue, and to confirm that you have read the Documentation
</div>
```

Comment: Very much this: _...not mixing AngularJS and jQuery..._ - within an Angular project, you should NOT ever need to use jQuery.  If you are tempted to use it, you're missing something about "the Angular way".  Also, may I recommend potentially offering up the `ng-hide` and `ng-show` versions of making this work? `ng-if` has important distinctions / use-cases that are different than hide / show.  And, as if those weren't enough options, one could even leverage `ng-style`, or `ng-class`....

Comment: @cale_b Good call, `ng-hide` would be a better equivalent to jQuery's `.hide()`.

Comment: @Lex This works! One question though, this seems to only change when the checkbox shows, is there a way to make it where it makes the text appear and disappear along with it? Edit: nevermind, I got it. Tried it with a different option and ctrl+F5 refreshed and it appears to be working correctly

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using the `ng-class` directive?

```
<div id="continueCheckbox" ng-class="selected: vim.request.requestType === 'test'"></div>
```

Then handle the style in .css file

```
.selected {
  display: none;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you wanted to use jQuery, you could just check the value of the select. You have it set up already.

```
var selectType=$(this).val();
if (selectType=="test") // instead of if ($("#test").is(":selected"))
```

You could also use vanilla JS with .value to do your comparison.